# Microsoft Word Enable Editing error

Tags: microsoft-word, editing

When opening a Word document that I am the author of I receive this message "enable editing" and It says, “Document locked by another user”. How can I keep that from happening?

Comment: Is the document on a network drive? Do you have it open in another program? Have you tried using a save-as to save it under a different name?

Comment: Along with what @curious_cat says, what version of Word are you using? Can you verify the document is truly opened by someone else? Can you close it and then open it to get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

I get this message frequently in Excel with spreadsheets stored on the network. It doesn't seem to matter whether they were recently closed or closed days ago & untouched since. I simply click the `Notify` button and go on my merry way. In a minute or two, it tells me that it's now available for editing, I click the `Read-Write` button, and all is good.

I'm not really sure what causes this, I just chalk it up to `Microsoft` and get on with my life.

In response to the comments on the OP, when the message says *Document locked by another user*, it thinks *you* are the one that has it open. If someone else has it open, it will give a user name/ID depending on network setup, and in that case, someone else really does have it open.